Ising model from the $\varphi^4$ scalar field theory
More than a year ago, I came across a paper (which I am unable to find at the moment) that mentioned the following statement: the Ising model is a discretized version of $\varphi^4$-scalar field theory in the large self-interaction limit, and the Bose-Hubbard model is a discretized version of the Dirac equation.
Recently, I encountered the same statement (the first one) in Chapter $1$ of the book Lattice QCD for Nuclear Physics. However, I am struggling to prove it — can anyone give me an outline of the solution or any hint?
Further details and my attempt: In general $d$-dimensions, the $\varphi^4$ (real) scalar field action is given by
$$S[\varphi] = \int d^d x \left[ \partial_\mu \varphi \,\partial^\mu \varphi - \frac{1}{2}m^2 \varphi^2 - \frac{1}{4!}\lambda \varphi^4 \right].$$
Restricting to a square lattice $\Lambda = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^d \,|\, x = a n;\, a \in \mathbb{R},\, n \in \mathbb{Z}^d \}$, this action can be discretized as
$$S[\varphi] = a^d \sum_x \left[ \partial_\mu \varphi \,\partial^\mu \varphi(x) - \frac{1}{2}m^2 \varphi(x)^2 - \frac{1}{4!}\lambda \varphi(x)^4 \right].$$
The book claims that in the limit $\lambda \to \infty$ (large self-interaction), this action reduces to
$$S_{\text{Ising}}[\varphi] = -\kappa \sum_x \sigma(x) \, \sigma(x + a\,\hat{\mu}),$$
where $\hat{\mu}$ are unit vectors in different directions $(\mu = 0, 1, 2, \dots, d)$, and $\sigma(x)$ is a rescaled field taking values in $\{-1,+1\}$.
This is the point where I am stuck — how can we deduce $S_{\text{Ising}}[\varphi]$ from $S[\varphi]$ in the $\lambda \to \infty$ limit?
Also, I am confused that $-\kappa \sum_x \sigma(x) \, \sigma(x + a\,\hat{\mu})$ is actually the Hamiltonian for the Ising model, but here it is seen that it is the discretization of the action! Why does this discrepancy appear?
I have seen this PSE question, but it is not very clear to me and also it doesn't completely answer my question.

Just by googling a bit you will find quite a few hints that would point you in the right direction, or at the very least allow you to ask mores specifically about the steps you don't understand.
